# why am I getting an error when trying to generate rsa 128

Tags: ubuntu, security, openssl, tls, rsa

For Educational purpose, I'm trying to create RSA 128 key pair using Openssl.
when trying the following command I get an error with "key size too small"

```
$ openssl genrsa 128
Generating RSA private key, 128 bit long modulus (2 primes)
140216022529216:error:04081078:rsa routines:rsa_builtin_keygen:key size too small:../crypto/rsa/rsa_gen.c:78:
```

I tried setting the security level to 0 as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level), but I still got the same problem.
I also tried building the software from source and setting DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=0, also it didn't work.

knowing that I'm currently using:

```
$ openssl version -a 
OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
built on: Mon Mar 22 11:37:17 2021 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/openssl-Juj39H/openssl-1.1.1f=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=2 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087423/how-long-would-it-take-to-factor-a-rsa-128-bit-key-length/16088524

Comment: @TomYan, I am just creating a challenge for CTF competition where participants have to break a random rsa key as the first step of solving the challenge. And they should be able to break it using factorDB, Cryptool, or any other script.

Comment: I'm running Debian 8 OpenSSL 1.0.1t and I can generate 31 bit RSA key https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/479

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is hard-coded to a minimum "secure" length, currently 512 bits (see RSA_MIN_MODULUS_BITS below). To circumvent it, for use in an embedded application, for example, you have to recompile OpenSSL:

```
crypto/rsa/rsa_local.h:14:#define RSA_MIN_MODULUS_BITS    512
--
crypto/rsa/rsa_gen.c:76:    if (bits < RSA_MIN_MODULUS_BITS) {
crypto/rsa/rsa_gen.c-77-        ok = 0;             /* we set our own err */
crypto/rsa/rsa_gen.c-78-        RSAerr(RSA_F_RSA_BUILTIN_KEYGEN, RSA_R_KEY_SIZE_TOO_SMALL);
crypto/rsa/rsa_gen.c-79-        goto err;
--
crypto/rsa/rsa_pmeth.c:464:        if (p1 < RSA_MIN_MODULUS_BITS) {
crypto/rsa/rsa_pmeth.c-465-            RSAerr(RSA_F_PKEY_RSA_CTRL, RSA_R_KEY_SIZE_TOO_SMALL);
crypto/rsa/rsa_pmeth.c-466-            return -2;
```

Comment: As for the reason its hard coded is that a 512 byte RSA is the minimum secure length but even that is to small to be actually secure (minimum in 2021 is I believe 2048)

Comment: It works, thanks. but had to use new fresh system without openssl installed on it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I'll edit my answer to add the detail. Interestingly, there is also the issue around export limitations on encryption from country to country. As such there are cases where a 128bit key might be mandatory, but not for SSH access, of course. It is still nice to be able to use the tools, however, to generate the key. In this case you can't with openSSL.